# Is the gradient descent algorithm guaranteed to converge after infinite iterations for a convex function?

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, gradient-descent

Whatsoever maybe the step size choice for the algorithm?
We talk about gradient descent not converging if we take a large step size,but I am not sure the algorithm won't converge ever?

Comment: I believe that gradient descent may get stuck in a local minimum, at least under certain circumstances, even with infinite iterations.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen My bad, I assume the function is convex,should've mentioned

Comment: Do you mean purely convex, or just monotonically decreasing?

Comment: I mean purely convex ,I guess we may get stuck in local minima for monotonically decreasing.

Comment: This question is better suited for http://stats.stackexchange.com/